# Buttons are displaying while loading but disappears after completion of loading what I m doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Here is vue code which will display subscription plan with button but while loading its displaying button(subcribe Now) but after completion of loading its not displaying button.
Please help me to resolve this issue. I m new tp webdevelopment.

```
<template>
  <div class="subscription-component">
    <div class="sub-title">
      Subscription
    </div>
    <div class="sub-msg">{{ subscriptionMsg }}</div>

    <div>
      <el-card class="box-card">
        <div slot="header" class="clearfix">
          <span class="plan">Free</span>
          <el-button class="price" style="float: right; padding: 3px 0" type="text">
            ₹0
          </el-button>
          <p>Trail</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text item">
          <ul class="fa-ul">
            <li><span class="icon"><el-button type="success" icon="el-icon-check" circle /></span>Free Access to All the Academic Videos for 2 days</li>
            <li><span class="icon"><el-button type="success" icon="el-icon-check" circle /></span>Free Access to all the Webcasted Live Classes for 2 days</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </el-card>
    </div>
    <div>
      <el-card class="box-card">
        <div slot="header" class="clearfix">
          <span class="plan">Premium</span>
          <el-button class="price" style="float: right; padding: 3px 0" type="text">
            ₹{{ userSubscrProduct.qtrSubscrAmt }}
          </el-button>
          <p>Quarterly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text item">
          <ul>
            <li><span class="icon"><el-button type="success" icon="el-icon-check" circle /></span>Free Access to All the Academic Videos for 2 days</li>
            <li>
              <span class="icon">
                <el-button type="success" icon="el-icon-check" circle />
              </span>Free Access to all the Webcasted Live Classes for 2 days
              <span v-if="!userSubscriptionDetails.existingSubscription && !userSubscriptionDetails.expiredSubscription" class="subscribe">
                <NuxtLink :to="`/subscription/${userSubscrProduct.idProduct}/${userSubscrProduct.idProductGroup}/QUARTER/${userSubscrProduct.qtrSubscrAmt}`">

                  <el-button class="el-buttons-sub" round @click="Subscribe()">
                    Subscribe now
                  </el-button>
                </NuxtLink>
              </span>
              <span v-if="userSubscriptionDetails.existingSubscription && !userSubscriptionDetails.expiredSubscription" class="subscribe">

                <span>
                  You have an active quarterly subscription!
                </span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </el-card>
    </div>
    <div>
      <el-card class="box-card">
        <div slot="header" class="clearfix">
          <span class="plan">Premium</span>
          <el-button class="price" style="float: right; padding: 3px 0" type="text">
            ₹{{ userSubscrProduct.annualSubscrAmt }}
          </el-button>
          <p>Annually</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text item">
          <ul class="fa-ul">
            <li><span class="icon"><el-button type="success" icon="el-icon-check" circle /></span>Free Access to All the Academic Videos for 2 days</li>
            <li>
              <span class="icon">
                <el-button type="success" icon="el-icon-check" circle />
              </span>Free Access to all the Webcasted Live Classes for 2 days
              <span v-if="!userSubscriptionDetails.existingSubscription && !userSubscriptionDetails.expiredSubscription" class="subscribe">
                <NuxtLink :to="`/subscription/${userSubscrProduct.idProduct}/${userSubscrProduct.idProductGroup}/'QUARTER'/${userSubscrProduct.qtrSubscrAmt}`">

                  <el-button class="el-buttons-sub" round @click="Subscribe()">
                    Subscribe now
                  </el-button>
                </NuxtLink>

              </span>
              <span v-if="userSubscriptionDetails.existingSubscription && !userSubscriptionDetails.expiredSubscription" class="subscribe">

                <span>
                  You have an active quarterly subscription!
                </span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </el-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  name: 'SubscriptionComponent',
  filters: {
    formatDate (dateToBeFormatted) {
      const date = new Date(dateToBeFormatted)
      return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')
    }
  },
  middleware: 'auth',

  data () {
    return {
      subscriptionMsg: null,
      details: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      userSubscrProduct: 'subscription/getUserSubscrProduct',
      userSubscriptionDetails: 'subscription/getUserSubscrDetails'

    })
  },
  mounted () {
    this.user = localStorage.getItem('vista-auth')
    const userObj = JSON.parse(this.user)
    this.surId = userObj.userSurId
    this.getUserSubscrDetails(this.surId)
    this.$store.dispatch('subscription/fetchUserSubscrProduct')

    debugger
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserSubscrDetails (surId) {
      this.details = await this.$store.dispatch('subscription/fetchUserSubscrDetails', surId)
      if (this.details.existingSubscription && !this.details.expiredSubscription) {
        this.subscriptionMsg = 'Your next payment date is ' + moment.utc(this.details.nextPaymentDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
      } else if (this.details.existingSubscription && this.details.expiredSubscription) {
        this.subscriptionMsg = 'Your subscription has expired, please renew'
      }
    }
  }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.subscription-component{
  .el-card__body{
    padding: 0rem;
  }
  .el-card__header {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  }
  .sub-msg{
  font-size: 2rem;
}
input{
  /* border-radius: 20px; */
}
 .text {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .item {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    @include sm{
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        font-size: 10px !important;
    }
  }

  .clearfix:before,
  .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
  }
  .clearfix:after {
    clear: both
  }

  .box-card {
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 5rem;
  }
  li{
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .icon{
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  .plan{
    font-weight: 500px;
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
  .sub-title{
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .price{
    margin-top: 5rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
  .subscribe{
    text-align: end;

  }
  .el-buttons-sub{
    background: #0B59A5;
    margin-left: 19rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 155px;
    @include sm{
         margin-left: 17rem;
         margin-top: 5rem;
    }
    @include md{
    margin-left: 35rem;
    }
  }
  p{
    font-size: 2.8rem;
  }
  ul{
    list-style: none;
    @include sm{
        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }
  }
}

</style>
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that v-if is wrong? Are you sure that button should be shown when subscription doesn't exist && doesn't expired? While script is checking values button is showing but after that it is hidden (because i.ex. subscription does expired)